# Testing Mono and Flux using Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, spring-webflux

Im currently writing some basic unit tests for my REST-Endpoints. I use [Mockito](http://site.mockito.org/) for that. Here one example:

```
@MockBean
private MyService service;

@Test
public void getItems() {
    Flux<Item> result = Flux.create(sink -> {
        sink.next(new Item("1"));
        sink.next(new Item("2"));
        sink.complete();
    });

    Mono<ItemParams> params = Mono.just(new ItemParams("1"));

    Mockito.when(this.service.getItems(params)).thenReturn(result);

    this.webClient.post().uri("/items")
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON)
            .body(BodyInserters.fromPublisher(params, ItemParams.class))
            .exchange()
            .expectStatus().isOk()
            .expectBodyList(Item.class).isEqualTo(Objects.requireNonNull(result.collectList().block()));
}
```

This implementation leads to the following error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Response body expected:<[Item(name=1), Item(name=2)]> but was:<[]>

> POST /items
> WebTestClient-Request-Id: [1]
> Accept: [application/stream+json]
> Content-Type: [application/stream+json]

Content not available yet

< 200 OK
< Content-Type: [application/stream+json;charset=UTF-8]

No content
```

When I exchange the parameter in the Mockito Statement with `Mockito.any()`

```
Mockito.when(this.service.getItems(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(result);
```

The test runs through successfully.
That means that for some reason the `params` I put into the `Mockito` Statement isnt equal to the `params` object which I put into `BodyInserters.fromPublisher(params, ItemParams.class)`

How am I supposed to test my functionality then?

**EDIT**

REST-Endpoint

```
@PostMapping(path = "/items", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON_VALUE)
public Flux<Item> getItems(@Valid @RequestBody Mono<ItemParams> itemParms) {
    return this.service.getItems(itemParms);
}
```

Comment: where is the assertion? Can you also add how did you mock the service?

Comment: I added the `MockBean` and the assertion is `.expectBodyList(Item.class).isEqualTo(Objects.requireNonNull(result.collectList().block()));`

Comment: try to show the endpoint implementation.. the important bits at least

Comment: I added the REST-Endpoint

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wouldn't the actual object, `@RequestBody Mono<ItemParams> itemParms`, be different than the one you create and pass in the test?

You could take advantage of `thenAnswer` in order to verify the content of the object that is actually passed to the service:

```
Mockito.when(this.service.getItems(Mockito.any()))
       .thenAnswer(new Answer<Flux<Item>>() {

    @Override
    public Flux<Item> answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
        Mono<ItemParams> mono = (Mono<ItemParams>)invocation.getArgument(0);

        if(/* verify that paseed mono contains new ItemParams("1")*/){
          return result;
        }

        return null;
    }
});
```

Comment: I do not really understand what you mean. I want to make sure that a `Mono<ItemParams>` is passed into the function. That is why I create one and put it into my `Mockito.when` and also inot my `BodyInserter`. That means it Is the same object for sure.

Comment: So you only want to make sure that an object of type Mono is passed? regardless of its content?

Comment: no. not regardless of its content, thats why I use `Mono<ItemParams>` and not `Mono`. The content of the `Mono` has to be of the type `ItemParams`

Comment: Not exactly sure what is the api / equals method of that class but the result based on the content of passed object is usually resolved by using the thenAnswer feature. The normal object expectency using when.. then does not seem to work here, hence the exception

Comment: Anyway. Your solution is working to force that the test only accepts `Mono<ItemParams>` as an input parameter.

Comment: Even if this is already accepted as an answer, I don't agree that this is a good approach. To write a proper test you should never introduce additional logic inside the test. You should just prepare your test doubles, prepare expected inputs, invoke your tested unit and verify expected output, that's all.